# How to always show menu in Firefox?

Tags: unity, firefox, globalmenu

**How do I get the application menu to be placed inside the Firefox window?**
I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and Firefox 12.0.

**I like Unity** as a whole, but the Mac-style "globalmenu" idea provides bad usability -- especially other users on my computer **never** find the menu and that prevents them from doing several tasks, like printing.

I've run the command `sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu` to put the menu back into the application window for most applications -- except Firefox.

I've seen that there have been [tricks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98864/how-can-i-re-enable-the-global-menu-in-firefox) to achieve the reverse, probably with older Firefox versions that didn't support *globalmenu* yet. Isn't there a similar trick to go the other direction now?

Comment: Firefox uses it's own extension for this, `firefox-globalmenu`

Comment: @Uri: they use an extension to _support_ globalmenu, not to _remove_ it, right? I've checked _Tools>Add-ons_ in my Firefox and there are no extensions relating to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete, Remove or Uninstall the package `firefox-globalmenu`

> **Unity appmenu integration for Firefox**
>
> This package provides an extension which adds support for the Unity
> appmenu to Firefox